# Converting classes to an library

Tags: iphone

Hi experts i have created a set of UItableviewcustom cell classes. Now can i group those classes to an static library so that i can include that library in whichever project i want and i can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it really isn't worth the trouble... with the rate that they keep on releasing new SDKs, and considering that you'd have to make it a Universal binary supporting both the simulator and the iPhone device, it really isn't worth the effort... I'd just save the ".h" and ".m" files and drop them in a new project.

However, if you are absolutely determined to go that route... I do have some articles on creating iPhone frameworks: [here](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/cross-compile-for-the-iphone). Note that they are somewhat outdated (circa  iPhoneOS3.1), so I don't know how much has changed, and I've since converted to the Android camp... but you still might find the info there useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael but i want to know what is the procedure to do that and is there any changes in the code to covert it to library.

Comment: @PrithviRaj, no you don't have to make changes to the code... it is more a matter of lots of build system craziness to ensure it gets compiled for all the appropriate architectures with the right compiler flags, is merged into a universal binary static library, and then packaged up in the iPhone framework bundle format.

Comment: ok thanks Michael i wil just investigate on this more on build settings:)